# keycloak behind nginx login fails, port number missing from post etc

Tags: nginx, proxy, keycloak

Keycloak losing hold of the port number passed when entering the page: **30666**

The submit button however does not contain ip+port number only ip-address is used here. Since the post fails.

And redirect fails...

**How can I make Keycloak work behind the proxy?**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The keycloak is running in a kubernetes cluster behind an NGinx proxy with the following conf:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log /dev/stderr warn;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

# make sure to set plaintext JWT_SECRET environment variable
env JWT_SECRET;

http {

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    lua_package_path "/usr/local/openresty/lualib/?.lua;;";

    server {
        listen 8080;
        root /;

        # load index page from nginx implementing the KC javascript:
        location / {
            index index.htm index.html;
        }

        location /auth {
            proxy_pass http://idp:8080/auth;
            proxy_http_version 1.1; # this is essential for chunked responses to work
            proxy_buffering    off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        # Secured endpoints
        location /secure/ {
            access_by_lua_file /bearer.lua;

            default_type text/plain;
            echo "<p>i am protected by jwt<p>";
        }
    }
}
```

My idp deployment looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.2.0 ()
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: idp
  name: idp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: idp
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: pass
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: admin
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: 'true'
        image: jboss/keycloak
        name: idp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9990
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Comment: Today I would run the Keycloak instance behind an [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) or similar. The config is easier that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is the `proxy_set_header $host`, it should be `$host:$server_port`

Additionally, the /auth URI suffixed to the proxy URL is not required. If it is not specified then Nginx will transmit the URI without changing it.

The config should be:

```
location /auth {
        proxy_pass http://idp:8080;
        ...
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```

Reference http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Note: Keycloak Clients may require a HTTPS URL. If you enable HTTPS in Nginx then remember to also pass the scheme to Keycloak with the x-forwarded-proto header.

```
        proxy_set_header x-forwarded-proto $scheme;
```

Comment: Yes! `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;` made the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: And `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` works even better... (reflects docker port mapping )

Answer (score 1):

You must add the following header as well

```
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my config:

```
location /restapi {
    proxy_pass http://api:8080/api;
   }

location /auth {
  proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

In docker:

```
..
keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:16.1.1
    container_name: keycloak
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "9400:8080"
    environment:
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).